# How to setup 301 permanent redirect for following?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect

Im trying to figure out how to setup a 301 permanent redirect for the following paths.

From: /restaurants/casa-villa.html

To: /restaurants/casa-villa

Thanks!
Jake

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it this way? I think you can just alias/rewrite it in Apache (assuming you're on LAMP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule restaurants/(.*).html /restaurants/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I was looking for some regex - sorry should have been more clear. So if there are 100 restaurnts - what variable can I pass so that the .html gets dropped off?